# irb --simple-prompt -rrbconfig not working

Tags: ruby, irb

I am new to Ruby programming. I am reading a book (The Well Grounded Rubyist Second Edition), which says following:

> Ruby can tell you where its installation files are located. To get the
>   information while in an irb session, you need to preload a Ruby
>   library package called rbconfig into your irb session.

```
$ irb --simple-prompt -rrbconfig
```

But for some reason, I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from /Users/ip/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
SyntaxError ((irb):2: syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
irb --simple-prompt -rrbconfig
                    ^)
```

Comment: I can't repro this on my 2.5.1 setup (using `rbenv`)

Comment: You're trying to run `irb --simple-prompt -rrbconfig` from inside irb, you should run that from the shell.